# "Correcting" code taken from reliable source?

Tags: discussion

Someone posted an [html/css question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33220474/in-css-how-do-i-constrain-the-width-of-a-middle-column-of-text/33220593#33220593) the other day and I answered it by directly referencing a piece of [code found on w3.org](http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/leaders.en.html).

I know I found exactly the answer the OP was looking for, and since my answer was taken from a reliable source I didn't test it or check it for errors.

The code I pasted was for how to generate dot leaders, and this is the markup:

```
<ul class=leaders>
  <li><span>Salmon Ravioli</span>
    <span>7.95</span>
  <li><span>Fried Calamari</span>
    <span>8.95</span>
  <li><span>Almond Prawn Cocktail</span>
    <span>7.95</span>
  <li><span>Bruschetta</span>
    <span>5.25</span>
  <li><span>Margherita Pizza</span>
    <span>10.95</span>
</ul>
```

At a quick glance, the markup looks fine, but if you look closer you'll notice that there is no closing list element `</li>` tag anywhere. Another user pointed this out and edited my answer.

I found this to be peculiar, given the fact that I had never seen such formatting (for `li`) but on the other hand the code was taken from no else than the World Wide Web Consortium. So I googled it and found that the closing `</li>` tag is actually [optional](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/syntax.html#optional-tags).

> *An li element's end tag may be omitted if the li element is immediately followed by another li element or if there is no more content in the parent element.*

So my question here is, which would be the *right/best* format of this code **for an answer** here on Stackoverflow?
Should the conventional ways of markup-formatting be upheld or should quoted information from reliable sources always remain unedited?

Comment: Simply state that the code was "derived" from the source rather than copied from the source. Same effect, but makes it clear that it may have been modified by you.

Comment: That's a very good idea indeed.

Comment: Adding that note as well would be a valuable addition to your answer, for all future visitors, who may wonder why your answer diverges from "the standard".

Comment: I would leave it as found on W3C, and add a note explaining `</li>` is optional. This way there is more to learn from the answer.

Comment: I honestly didn't know that there are optional tags in html5. This seems strange to me, but kind of makes sense considering `<script>` and `<template>` elements may be children of `<ul>` or `<ol>`. You can roll it back if you want.

Comment: Please consider changing the link text in your question from "W3.com" to "w3.org", as that is the canonical URL. W3.com is _not_ associated with the World Wide Web Consortium. Also, minor thing, but the name of the website (and company) is Stack Overflow, two words.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan whoops! Fixed the typo.

Comment: Btw, if you see somebody who made a wrong or questionable edit, you can talk to them directly by using `@Editor'sDisplayName` in the comments under the post. There won't be name autocompletion, but they will receive a notification. This doesn't work for rejected edit suggestions. The editor actually has to be in the edit history.

Comment: Another thing I noticed is the missing quotes around the class-name in the `ul`. hmm...

Comment: @Chris Also optional, if the attribute value is a single word. Not recommended though.

Comment: If it's actually a quote then I'd always leave it as-is (though presumably you'd want to quote a better source if it was wrong). Perhaps they were an XHTML "pro".

Comment: FWIW, the entire kerfuffle likely would have been avoided had you, before posting an answer, done a quick search on Stack Overflow to determine that the question was in fact a duplicate of [many existing questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcss%5D+table+of+contents+dots), including [one particular example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2508732) that included [an answer that referenced the same exact example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8132612) you did.

Comment: @PeterDuniho kerfuffle?? I see it as a learning experience. Why "upgrade it" to something dramatic when it never was? Nobody seems bothered by neither this meta post nor my answer, apart from yourself. Also, considering the fact that there are at least 3 other possible answers to the question, it only seems reasonable to mark it as "too broad" rather than a duplicate, and especially so when OP didn't include any code in his/her post.

Comment: I wonder why the post was deleted, rather than just closed.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This edit should be rolled back.

Yes, if the edit had been made to make the HTML more readable, then the edit would have been valid. Whether it actually is more readable is arguable, but I suspect pretty much everyone will at least agree that it's not less readable.

But that's not why the edit was made. The edit summary states "pro-tip: produce valid HTML". Editing an answer that contains perfectly valid HTML while claiming the edit is to make it valid is just wrong.

The edit summary matters. People do look at the revision history of answers. Leaving it as it is now spreads misinformation.

Comment: Also, writing "pro tip" as edit remark could be considered rude.

Comment: Maybe a comment should be added to address the issue to the "pro-" editor as well. (Unless an automatic notification is generated anyway.)

Comment: I disagree that the edit *should* be rolled back - I think a comment on the answer explaining that the original was valid HTML, but the edit is preferred best practice is more informative and leaves the answer in a better state for future users.

Comment: @Jason It's not a preferred best practice, at least not a generally accepted one. You may personally prefer it, that's fine, but your preference is not universal. (The original version is not a generally preferred best practice either. There's simply no general agreement.)

Comment: That my preference is not universal doesn't mean that it shouldn't be :)

Comment: @hvd I went looking for *anyone* who recommended omitting closing tags, and found no less than [Google doing so](https://google.github.io/styleguide/htmlcssguide.xml?showone=Optional_Tags#Optional_Tags) - however, even in that circumstance, it makes far more sense to *write* the HTML with closing tags and then process it with a (perhaps hypothetical, at the moment) HTML compiler to produce the output with closing tags omitted... I can't think of any situation where I would want to *maintain* their recommended example.

Comment: @Lundin - it is rude if you are right, moronic if you are wrong. Pro-tip, in this case moronic :)

Answer (score 5):

My gut feeling is do what makes the answer better.  If someone quoted some code from somewhere but was nigh unreadable for formatting reasons, I would expect them to format it better.  In this case, I'd expect the closing tags would cause less confusion and problems in browsers.  I would add the closing tags in and maybe make a note that you added them.

If you choose to leave it alone, I would add a note with the link mentioning that the closing tags are optional.

As long as you aren't changing things in any major way or in a way that makes the code wrong or contradicts what you are quoting, I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: As far as I know, browsers are almost always very good at handling missing closing tags, even when they *aren't* officially optional. So there aren't likely to be any real problems, except perhaps with poorly-written regex parsers, but we know the `<center>` cannot hold on those anyway.

Comment: Yes, it's certainly valid to omit them, but by doing so you're likely to draw attention of other users who will dispute the correctness, which is of course irrelevant in this case. Better to just have them than to have to have that discussion in comments in my opinion.

Comment: @NathanTuggy Agreed that most browsers do just fine.  But I know I've seen more than a few pages turn out funny because of a missing tag (and finding that tag can be a pain).  Also, if you wanted to parse that HTML with a library, who knows how it would handle it.  At any rate, fixing it doesn't hurt in this specific case.

Comment: @Becuzz: If you're parsing with l33td00d's s00perSpeedy HTML library (v3.14), sure, there's probably going to be glitches. Anything vaguely professional, though, like the libraries present in various languages, I would be quite surprised to see choke on that.

Comment: @NathanTuggy Yup.  [But it wouldn't be the first time someone's tried something crazy with regards to HTML.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/550062)

Comment: @NathanTuggy: having an XHTML parser somewhere in the chain can be enough to turn `<iframe></iframe>` into `<iframe />` into (in the browser) `<iframe>`-and-whoops-no-end-tag, so it's not as "that's what you get for using homebrew tools" as you might expect.

Comment: @KevinB, *Better to just have them than to have to have that discussion in comments IMO* - I disagree. The point of the discussion is to find a common ground (and differences) and figure out the truth. Without discussion, those who think `</li>` is required will go on having false information. With discussion, more information is shared and arguments from both sides can be posed as to best practices vs legal html.

Comment: Right, but it isn't  relevant to the question being asked in any way shape or form, and isn't an issue as serious as sql injection. No discussion of it needs to happen in the comments to that question.

Comment: Exactly. Pointing out how it is, is an educational experience for those who don't know. Personally, I'm fond of pointing out that for instance `tbody` has an optional _start tag_ as well, which means that even if you write `<table><tr>` you will end up with a `tbody` in your table. People often don't realise that.